# SELECT INNER JOIN only returns one result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having trouble selecting some data from 2 tables in my database.

The tables are `psthostess` and `psttodo-uit`.

In my `psthostess` I want to select the fields `Code` and `Name`.
In my `psttodo-uit` I want to select:

- sum of PB=1
- sum of PG=1
- sum of PA=1
- sum of h.GoedkeuringDoorNew=GF
- sum of h.GoedkeuringDoorNew=SB
- sum of h.GoedkeuringDoorNew=VIA
- sum of h.Blanco

This is my query:

```
SELECT p.Code, p.Name, sum(h.PB = 1), sum(h.PG = 1), sum(h.PA = 1), 
       sum(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'GF'), sum(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'SB'),  
       sum(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'VIA'), sum(h.Blanco)
   FROM psthostess p
   INNER JOIN `psttodo-uit` h ON h.`Hostess Code` = p.Code
   WHERE p.Indienst = 1
```

The problem is that I always get a result of one row. But there are multiple rows in `psthostess` with `Indienst = 1` (WHERE). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group it by non-aggregated columns.

```
SELECT p.Code, p.Name, sum(h.PB = 1), 
sum(h.PG = 1), sum(h.PA = 1), sum(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'GF'), 
sum(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'SB'), sum(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'VIA'), sum(h.Blanco)
FROM psthostess p
INNER JOIN `psttodo-uit` h ON h.`Hostess Code` = p.Code
WHERE p.Indienst = 1
group by p.Code, p.Name
```